# Which feature/function of C++ to test if a function is being executed?

Tags: c++, function

I am a novice in coding and I have a library of functions to access a hardware.

I believe that the functions are being called correctly as there is no compilation error, but my concern is that they may not have returned any output.

So I want to be able to have some sort of indication that each individual functions are being executed and that they are returning something.

There is an error check function defined in the library but I would like to learn how to make one myself and what is this procedure called.

Is it Try and Exceptions?

Comment: Do you know how to use your debugger? It sounds like all you need is a debugger.

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: This is exactly what a debugger is designed to do. If you don't know how to use one, now is the perfect time to do so. There is no better tool available to a programmer for finding errors in logic or tracing through the flow of execution. And no, try and exceptions won't tell you whether code is being executed or not. A profiler might, but you probably don't have one available. Also, if your code is checking return values as it should, you'd know if the functions were returning values or not. Return values are useless if you don't use them.

Comment: Alright thanks for your advice, Alter Igel and Ken White!

Comment: I see a lot of people talking about debuggers here, but there is also this thing called "test driven development". Have a look at TDD & "google test". With this you will be able to make a stand-in class for your real code and really test that things are being called in the right order and/or number of times before even testing on hardware or having to debug code. With testdriven development I've found that 1) I end up with less debug /logging code in production code (asserts). 2) I don't reintroduce bugs I've fixed earlier and more.